# php variables won't save properly

Tags: php, javascript

I'm posting to a php script, and I want to update some already existing variables in the script. My javascript is this :

```
$('.submit_html').click( function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var requested = $('.page_select').val();
            var text = new Array($('.edit_html').val(), $('.header_val').val());
                $.post('data_handlers/get_content.php', {page: requested, action: 'update', text: text}, function(data) {
                       alert(data);

                                                });
                                                })
```

There really isn't anything complicated about the post, just a couple variables to tell the script what to do, and then a text variable, with the data in the first two spots of the array.

On the php side, I know it is getting the data correctly, but when I try to overwrite the current variable in the script, it doesnt stay saved after the php script completes.

php code:

```
if ($page == 'home') {
        $home = $text[0];
        $home_head = $text[1];
        return;

    }
```

So obviously, it is changing the variables during the execution, but reverting to the values that were manually saved in the script before. Is there anyway to actually have the values stay changed after the script ends?

Comment: One option is [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) and session variables.

Comment: Where do you want to keep these values?  Client side or server side?

Comment: Well in this php script, there are about 10 variables, that I would like to have dynamic values, so that when I post to the script with new values, it will permanently change them in the actual file.
To answer your question, server side, since I don't ever want to lose the value of the variables

Comment: I guess I want to use a php file to provide for me what a database does, but I'm hoping I won't need to use a database to save the information.

Comment: a php executable gets recreated for every request. To maintain state on the server side you need to store the variables somewhere: a file, a database, or a cache (if you are OK with them going away at some point.) Reading them in a php script will only inform the server side during those milliseconds that the php script executes.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was assuming, I guess my options are reading and writing from a file or setting up a database, thanks.

Comment: Really not a good idea to use `register_globals`. You should be using $_GET['page']`, not `$page`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [the session module](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) is ideal for what you are trying to do.